# Rails: Passing a condition to a controller and then using that in a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new at this, so any help is much appreciated.

While building a tabbed interface I am trying to reuse the same partial and controller and pass a :conditions to a controller to build every tab differently.

```
@wishes_category = Wish.find :all,
:order => 'id DESC',
:conditions => {:user_id => @current_user.id}
```

First tab would need something like `:category_id=>1` in the controller's :conditions thus limiting what I show in it.
I am trying to pass this condition to a partial which would use the a pre-limited @wishes_category with `:category_id=>1`

Thanks!
Naz

==

Based on what Erik said, I then limited the `@wishes_category` this way
`<% if category_id == wish.category_id %>` in the partial thus solving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass local parameters to a partial through its render tag using something like:

```
<%= render :partial => 'tab', :locals => {:category_id => 1} %>
```

This sets a local variable in the partial named `category_id` equal to 1. In your partial, it would be referenced simply using `<%= category_id %>`. Now you are able to render the same partial file multiple times in a page with different local variables.

Of course the variable `category_id` must exist in the partial before being used or it will throw an error. You can protect against this by checking `<% if local_assigns[:category_id] %>` first.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Erik!
I got the local variable category_id to be passed to all tabs. As a follow up, how would I use that to influence my @wishes_category controller to apply the condition?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your question earlier but I don't quite understand it... if you still need help please start another question and elaborate further. The actual reason I revisited this is that I realized the way to check if the local exists in the partial is by calling `if local_assigns[:category:id]`. I made the edit above.

Comment: Thanks Erik! I got it to work with your tip and will use the edited code to put in a check for the local.